# xlsxwriter: how "inf" value can be uncolored?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

using python package "xlsxwriter", I want to highlight cells in the following conditional range; 
                               value > 1 or value <-1
However, some cells have -inf/inf values and it fill colors them too (to yellow). Is thare any way to unhighlight them? 
I tried "conditional_format" function to uncolor them, but it doesn't work. 
[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMqhb.png)

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#FFBF00'}) #yellow
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#2E64FE'}) #blue
format3 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#FFFFFF'}) #white

c_fold=[data.columns.get_loc(col) for col in data.columns if col.startswith("fold")]
c_fold.sort() 


l=len(data)+1
worksheet.conditional_format(1,c_fold[0],l,c_fold[-1], {'type':'cell',
                                             'criteria' : '>',
                                             'value':1,
                                             'format':format1,
                                             })

worksheet.conditional_format(1,c_fold[0],l,c_fold[-1], {'type':'cell',
                                             'criteria' : '<',
                                             'value':-1,
                                             'format':format2,
                                             })

worksheet.conditional_format(1,c_fold[0],l,c_fold[-1], {'type':'text',
                                             'criteria' : 'begins with',
                                             'value':"-inf",
                                             'format':format3,
                                             })
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a lot of cases the answer to the question "how do I get this to work with XlsxWriter" is the same as the answer to the question "how do I get this to work with Excel".

If you try your example in Excel you will see that you get the same results as the XlsxWriter example. The `>` criteria is applies to `-inf` in Excel, thus it is highlighted as light orange. The fact that the following `containing` criteria also matches doesn't override the first matching criteria since Excel applies them in the order that the user supplies them.

The solution in Excel, and XlsxWriter, is to change the order that the rules are applied, like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('conditional_format.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add some formats to use in the conditional formats.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFBF00'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#2E64FE'})
format3 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFFFFF'})

# Write some sample data.
worksheet1.write('A1', 2)
worksheet1.write('A2', '-inf')
worksheet1.write('A3', -2)

# Write a conditional formats over the same range.
worksheet1.conditional_format('A1:A3', {'type': 'text',
                                        'criteria': 'begins with',
                                        'value': "-inf",
                                        'format': format3})

worksheet1.conditional_format('A1:A3', {'type': 'cell',
                                        'criteria': '>',
                                        'value': 1,
                                        'format': format1})

worksheet1.conditional_format('A1:A3', {'type': 'cell',
                                        'criteria': '<',
                                        'value': 1,
                                        'format': format2})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This would solve

```
worksheet.conditional_format(1,c_fold[0],l,c_fold[-1], {'type':'text',
                                         'criteria' : 'containing',
                                         'value':"-inf",
                                         'format':format3,
                                         })
```

Comment: I tried that one too, but it didn't work. actually I tried other combinations like type: "cell" and criteria "==" , but it didn't work either. By the way, I used function "to_excel" with "na_rep='nan'" option to deal with nan/inf values. Can it be the problem?